# Filter 2 types of columns in oracle

Tags: c#, sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a query(Oracle), and it returns the following dataset,
FX_RCF
FX_CCF
FX_NXT_RCF
FX_NXT_CCF

> So, I need to remove FX_NXT_RCF and FX_NXT_CCF from the result set.

My Query

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'TAXCAT' AND column_name LIKE 'FX_%'
```

Comment: Caveman way `AND (column_name LIKE 'FX_R%' OR column_name LIKE 'FX_C%')` For index use you can change it to `and column_name IN(colx,coly)` EDIT `AND column_name NOT LIKE 'FX_N%'`

Comment: @Mihai Please see the updated question.I need to remove the FX_NXT_RCF and FX_NXT_CCF

Comment: try this `SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name not in ('FX_NXT_RCF ','FX_NXT_CCF ')`.